# Spring MVC + jquery data binding null for large request

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc

I have a web application using Spring MVC and Jquery at the front end. Data binding from the jsp to controller works nice and dandy for small data. My form binds to an object containing a list of objects.

The problem arises when it tries to handle around **3000** records, only **2000** records are found on `myList`. with **10000** records, `myList` contains `null`

```
Public class DataBindingObject{
private List<MyObject> myList
}

     /**
     *This is my controller
     */
    @RequestMapping(value="/submit", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView submitRequest(@ModelAttribute("submitAllocations") DataBindingObject dto) throws ServiceException {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("redirect:/search");
    }
```

i checked tomcat logs if i reached max size, but no. 
anything i missed? thanks in advance!

**EDIT**:

I checked using Firebug if the whole request payload is being sent to the controller, and apparently it does. For some reason, the controller is not able to **bind** the entire request payload. Whats strange is it seems to be capped at 2000 for fairly large data, and `null` on large data. Our app uses `WebDataBinder` for binding the request into our object, and it seems that therein lies the problem.

```
/**
     * Sets the initial list size for arrays used in ModelAttributes.
     * 
     * @param dataBinder
     */
    @InitBinder
    private void initBinder(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
        dataBinder.setAutoGrowCollectionLimit(listSizeLimit);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally found the culprit! Tomcat had a `maxPostSize`, `maxPostSize` `maxParameterCount` settings that limit our request! strangely though, it was not throwing an `java.lang.IllegalStateException` like I read from others, which made it so difficult to debug.

I just added those settings in my `server.xml` located at `my/tomcat/directory/conf` and set it at either `-1` or `0` to disable the limit.

I didnt care why it was not throwing an exception, though. But I am glad we found the solution.

```
 <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
                   maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
                   clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
               keystoreFile="/bin/muKeystore.jks"
               keystorePass="myPassword" maxPostSize="0" maxParameterCount="-1" maxHeaderCount="-1" />
```

reference: 
http://sisis.bth.rwth-aachen.de:8080/docs/config/ajp.html